# SAS cumalitive/recursive addition of Column cells

Tags: sas

I have a question regarding recursive/cumulative addition of a particular column for example: Click on example

How do I write this in SAS code which generates cumalitive addition with respect to column. Please help me with this.

Thank you in Advance

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N68Lp.png)

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

use sum statement

```
 data have;
 input val;
 datalines;
 1
 2
 3
 ;
 data want;
  set have;
  newval+val;
  run;
```

Comment: For new SAS coders, the `SUM` statement is a language element unique to SAS.  The SUM statement `<variable> + <expression>;` is equivalent to `retain <variable> 0;
<variable> = sum ( <variable>, <expression> );`  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000289454.htm

Answer (score 0):

Using `Retain` functionality.

You can reuse the code below as basis for any iterative/cumulative calculations.

```
 data have;
 input A;
 datalines;
 1
 2
 3
 ;
 run;
 data want;
  set have;
  Retain B;
  /* If condition to initialize B only once, _N_ is the current row number */
  if _N_= 1  then B=0;
  B=B+A;
/* put statement will print the table in the log */
  put _all_;
  run;
```

Output:

```
 A=1 B=1 _N_=1
 A=2 B=3 _N_=2
 A=3 B=6 _N_=3
```

Comment: This will also work but I will have to have an else statement. The 0 is the initial value for B, so in Row 1: A= 1, B=B+A (0+1), Row 2: A=2 , B=B+A ((0+1)+2).  Without initial 0 Values ale B will be . as .+1=.